# Unable to create object of type new InternetExplorerDriver(capabalities)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to create a driver as follows:

```
driver=InternetExplorerDriver(Capabilities capabilities);
```

But I don't see a constructor of that type in my `InternetExplorerDriver` class.

[image]

Please help me know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET bindings have implemented a pattern where one uses type-safe options classes rather than a generic dictionary object where the user could put vastly invalid information. The `InternetExplorerOptions` contains properties for all capabilities you would ordinarily use. In the unlikely event that you need an option for which there is not yet a type-safe property, you can use the `AddAdditionalCapability` method to add the (for now) unsupported option.

Comment: This did add the new capability. But did not help me in accomplishing my task

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but does this answer not answer the question you asked? I'm sorry it didn't help you accomplish your task. Perhaps you should ask a new question detailing the actual task you're attempting.